# How to reload my index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this filter in my tutos index:

```
 = simple_form_for :query, url: tutos_path, method: :get,  wrapper: :inline_form, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f|
        = f.input  :keyword, placeholder: "Keyword"
        = f.input  :category, collection: (Category.all.map {|c| c.name}) ,  prompt: "Select a category"
        = f.input  :user, collection: (User.order('nickname ASC').all.map {|u| u.nickname}), prompt: "Select a user"
        = f.button :submit, "Find", class:"btn btn-warning"
        = link_to t("search_form.best"),  best_voted_path, class: "btn btn-default"
        = link_to t("search_form.all"),  tutos_path, class: "btn btn-default"


        -if user_signed_in?
          = link_to t("search_form.create"), new_tuto_path, class:"btn btn-success"
```

After filtering I can't get back to my tutos_path through my link_to:
I have this error:

```
NoMethodError at /en/tutos
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

in my controller I have:

```
 def index
   @tutos = Tuto.all
   filter_tutos
  end

 def filter_tutos
   @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:query][:keyword]).includes(:user, :category) if params[:query][:keyword].present?
   @tutos = Tuto.joins(:user).where('users.nickname LIKE ?', params[:query][:user]) if params[:query][:user].present?
   @tutos = Tuto.joins(:category).where('categories.name LIKE ?', params[:query][:category]) if params[:query][:category].present?
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from your `params[:query][:keyword].present?` and the other ones alike, because it's evaluated as params, then params[:query]. If one of these evaluates to nil, and then trying to run `nil[:query]`, hence `[]` isn't defined on `NilClass`, it returns an error.

You'll need to check for nil in the function:

```
 def filter_tutos
   return if params[:query].nil? # Don't bother, if the query is nil
   @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:query][:keyword]).includes(:user, :category) if params[:query][:keyword].present?
   @tutos = Tuto.joins(:user).where('users.nickname LIKE ?', params[:query][:user]) if params[:query][:user].present?
   @tutos = Tuto.joins(:category).where('categories.name LIKE ?', params[:query][:category]) if params[:query][:category].present?
 end
```

As far as I remember, `params` is always set in the Controller. If this is not the case, you'll need to adapt your nil-checks for that as well.

To make it fit your own answer, and have a fallback method, you could do like so, to check if

```
def index
  filter_tutos if params[:query].present?
  @tutos ||= Tuto.all
end
```

To make sure that @tutos are set. It'll be set to `Tuto.all` if it's nil from the method `filter_tutos`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out...

in my controller:

```
 def index
    if params[:query].present?
      filter_tutos
    else
      @tutos = Tuto.all
    end
  end
```

in my view instead of my `= link_to t("search_form.all"),  tutos_path, class: "btn btn-default"`

I did:

`= link_to t("search_form.all"), {controller: 'tutos', action: 'index'}, class: "btn btn-success"`

Comment: Please note if you dont have a fallback in filter_tutos, and therefore if `params[:query]` is set, but not with the 3 keywords you have, `@tutos` will be nil in your view. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hello, sorry I posted my own answer before I see yours !
Thanks for your suggestion.
  Btw , it works as expected